# Fetched iOS contacts to tableview but the Tableview data is not showing until I click another tab bar item and come back to the tableview tab

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

This function is called in my "viewDidLoad()". I am able to retrieve all contacts successfully, though the data doesn't show up, until I click another tab bar item, then return to the tableview tab bar item. Here is my code ..

```
 func getContacts()
     {
         print("Attempting to fetch Contacts")
         let store = CNContactStore()

         store.requestAccess(for: .contacts) { (granted, err) in
             if let err = err {
                 print("failed to request Access", err)
                 return
             }
         if granted {
             print("access granted")
             let keys = [CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey]
             let request = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: keys as [CNKeyDescriptor])
            request.sortOrder = CNContactSortOrder.userDefault
             do {
                var contactNames = [ContactNames]()

                 try store.enumerateContacts(with: request, usingBlock: {(contact, stopPointerIfYouWantToStopEnumerating) in

                    contactNames.append(ContactNames(contact: contact))

                 })

                self.contactsArray = contactNames


             }catch let err {
                 print("Failed to enumerate contacts", err)
             }


         } else{
             print("access denied")
             }

         }

     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data won’t have been loaded by the first time the tableview is populated. It works when you navigate using the tabs because the data has loaded at the point you return to the tableview tab and this forces a reload of the tableview.

Assuming your tableview data source is using `self.contactsArray` you just need to call `tableview.reloadData()` after assigning your data to `self.contactsArray`.

Be sure to do this on the main thread.

```
self.contactArray = contactNames
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Just to note. The DispatchQueue should be located where your ”self.contactsArray = contactNames” is. You might also add that piece or code inside your DispatchQueue. :)

Comment: Updated to include the assignment line to make it extra clear where it should go. 

Comment: I would add the `self.contactsArray = contactNames` inside the DispatchQueue. Because there is no reason you should set the array before the block is fully completed. :) But that might work just as fine :)

Comment: There is no reason to force it onto the main queue that I can see. The main queue is best left to handle Ui stuff.

Comment: That’s true. Just a thought I had... Cuz when the DispatchQueue is done you’ll set the array. But I just came back from the club so can’t really think 100% clear atm! Haha. :)

Comment: This worked, I am relatively new to iOS development and now going to read the docs about DispatchQueue. Thanks a lot !